unique_ptr is not changing object it's pointing to
In my project, I load a lot of data out of JSON files. To make this faster, I use one thread that is loading the files' content into a std::deque and another thread formatting the data from the std::deque.
The function that loads the data into the std::deque is using a std::unique_ptr to access the deque. The problem is: the changes made to the unique_ptr are not being made to the original std::deque.
That's my first question: Does a unique_ptr (or shared_ptr) modify the object used to initialize it with std::make_unique() (or std::make_shared())?
I solved this with using a reference, but another question still remains: Does a unique_ptr need the object it's pointing to, like a raw pointer does?
Because, at another point of my project, I use the loaded data by giving a unique pointer to that data to another function. Do I need to store the data? Or will it be enough to store the unique_ptr, even when the data used to initialize it is destroyed?
Here's the code I used for loading the JSONs:
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

typedef std::deque<std::pair<array<array<double, 28>, 28>, unsigned int>> threadLoadList;
typedef vector<std::pair < std::shared_ptr<vector<double>>, std::shared_ptr<vector<double>> >> dataPointer;


namespace data {
    std::mutex mtx{};
    vector<vector<double>> training_desired_output{};
    vector<vector<double>> training_images{};
    dataPointer pic_val_pairs{};
}

void loadTrainImages(std::unique_ptr<threadLoadList> storage) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 60000; ++i) {
        std::ifstream str(data::training_data_path + "\\image" + Format_number(i) + ".json");
        nlohmann::json data = nlohmann::json::parse(str);
        data::mtx.lock();
        storage->push_back(std::make_pair<array<array<double, 28>, 28>, unsigned int>(
            data["pic"],
            data["val"]
        ));
        data::mtx.unlock();
        str.close();
    }
}

int main() {
    threadLoadList pics_vals{};

    auto load = std::thread(loadTrainImages, std::make_unique<threadLoadList>(pics_vals));

    while(true) {
        data::mtx.lock();
        unsigned int size = pics_vals.size();
        data::mtx.unlock();
        if(size > 0) {
            std::cout << "got one\n";
            data::mtx.lock();
            std::pair<array<array<double, 28>, 28>, unsigned int> copy = pics_vals.front();
            pics_vals.pop_front();
            data::mtx.unlock();

            //format 28 x 28 array
            vector<double> pic{};
            for(int i = 27; i > -1; --i) {
                for(int n = 0; n < 28; ++n) {
                    pic.push_back(copy.first[i][n]);
                }
            }

            // format val-array
            vector<double> val(10);
            val = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
            val[copy.second] = 1.0;

            // do I need to store the data (pic and val) pic_val_pairs is pointing to globally? Or is it enought, to store the pointers to them and have pic and val being destroyed?
            data::training_images.push_back(pic);
            data::training_desired_output.push_back(val);
            data::pic_val_pairs.push_back(
                std::make_pair<std::shared_ptr<vector<double>>, std::shared_ptr<vector<double>>>(
                std::make_shared<vector<double>>(data::training_images.back()),
                std::make_shared<vector<double>>(data::training_desired_output.back())
            ));
        }
        if(data::pic_val_pairs.size() >= 60000) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Do something
}

I expected unique_ptr to behave like a raw pointer.
Running the code above showed me, that pics_vals doesn't change when loadTrainImage modifies the pointer to pics_vals.
I feel like unique_ptr copies the values into a new object, because the process memory contains 800MB after loading, but the JSON files only have 180MB in total. Is that right?
For loading the data, it was easily solved by using references, but in the part //Do something I can't use references because I need to randomly shuffle the pic_val_pairs.

Look at the documentation of make_unique. It creates a new object from its arguments which is then managed by the unique_ptr, i.e. it manages a copy. If the thread is supposed to reference the variable in main, then why use unique_ptr at all? It doesn't seem that you want the thread to own the list. It seems like you just want to pass a non-owning reference.

"but in the part //Do something I can't use references, cause I need to randomly shuffle the pic_val_pairs.": I don't understand what you mean here or why you can't pass by-reference.

It seems that you don't understand what a std::unique_ptr is.  In fact, the issue you are experiencing is because you are not expecting this data to be unique.  You have a unique pointer named storage, and you are wondering why a different variable pics_vals is not the same data.  This code would be much better if you removed the unique pointers.

I don't understand the huge downvotes tbh. Even if he wouldn't have asked the question if he read the docs carefully and took his time to understand it, this is the case with most of us and most of the questions. There wouldn't be a need for Stackoverflow if all of us read the docs carefully and took our time to understand it.

I expected unique_ptr to behave like a raw pointer.  A unique_ptr does not behave like a raw pointer.

Your opening paragraph, which is where the most significant information should go, mentions your project, loading data, JSON files, threading, std::deque, and formatting the data. None of this has any direct bearing on your question. This means people looking for answers are likely to dismiss your question as irrelevant even if it matches what they are looking for. Start your question with your question. If you feel strongly that your personal story of how you arrived at this question is relevant (it usually is not, but occasionally it has useful context), it can go at the end.

"Here's the code I used for loading the JSONs:" -- If your code demonstrates anything more than "unique_ptr is not changing object it's pointing to" then it is too long. Get rid of the distractions, and distill your code down to a [mre] focused exclusively on the subject of your question. Usually half a dozen lines is enough, (But make sure it is still complete enough to be copied, compiled, and run.)

The linked duplicate has a good example of the level of detail desired in a [mre]. No threading, no JSON, just simply focused on a unique_ptr not changing the object to which it points. Sixteen lines total, eight of them "significant".


I expected unique_ptr to behave like a raw pointer.

That was your mistake.  If you want the behavior of a raw pointer, you should use a raw pointer.
You can fix this code by replacing std::unique_ptr with raw pointers.
A raw pointer can point to your pics_vals object, while std::make_unique creates a pointer to something new and unique.

I assumed, that i missed something with how unique_ptr is used.
thanks to everyone commenting here.
